# I can't find the css class that would work for this slider

Tags: css, class

I'm trying to create an animation like the one present on this slider: 
Elvetiajobs.ro

And recreate it on the easy slider on https://elvetia.startsmalltesting.com/

The last one is made with Enfold.

I'm trying to use this code that would do the job, yet, I can't find the CSS class that would work

```
{
transform: matrix3d(1.1,0,0.00,0,0.00,1.1,0.00,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)!important;
-webkit-transform: 
matrix3d(1.1,0,0.00,0,0.00,1.1,0.00,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)!important;
transform-origin: right top 0px; 
transition: all 1s linear 0s;
-webkit-transform-origin: right top 0px; 
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear 0s;

}
```

Comment: Put your code so we can try to help you..

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using wordpress, and they're too, specifically they're using revolution slider plugin which has that effect built-in, i wouldn't bother with complex css.

You can either use revolution slider too, or search for a slider plugin with that effect, this https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/ken-burns-slider/ Rolo Slider has it for instance, it's called the Ken Burns effect by the way or **zooming effect** (to help you with your search in case).

Comment: So, just add a new plugin for that?

Comment: You're awesome NOTSURE

Comment: No need of a new plugin if you use that instead of what you're using.

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. The question is off topic anyway so this will all get deleted later.